# Read placeholders in micronaut aspect

Tags: java, micronaut

I want to create an [aspect](https://docs.micronaut.io/1.2.11/guide/index.html#aop) in micronaut to have a generic way to send an event to a queue with the information that is passed to some methods, as well as some information from the context e.g. **method parameters**, ***method response***, ***duration***, ***exceptions***, ***request headers (for api methods)*** etc. However, I want to define in the annotation what data should be added to the event. I have a working example using spring boot and SpEL:

```
@Event( <- This is the annotation to create the event
     @Detail(key = "salary", value = "#request.salary.toString()"), <- This is the SpEL
     @Detail(key = "ipAddress", value = "#HttpServletRequest.getHeader('x-forwarded-for').split(',')[0]"), <- This gets the client ipAddress from the context
     @Detail(key = "userAgent", value = "#HttpServletRequest.getHeader('user-agent')"") <- This gets the browser

)
public void MyMethod(RequestInformation request){
}
```

In that example above the event is created only with 3 properties and send to the queue in json format

```
{
 details:[
    "salary":"6000",
    "ipAddress":"180.30.115.62",
    "userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.2 Safari/605.1.15"
 ]
}
```

I know that SpEL is not supported by Micronaut as it states in the [documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-spring/latest/guide/#springLimitations): `Spring Expression Language (SpEL) - SpEL expressions are not supported, property placeholders are however`

I've tried reading about property placeholders but most of the examples are related to getting values from .yml files.

I'd like to know if there is a way to do something similar without creating my own language in micronaut. Also, migrate to spring boot is not an option.

I'll thank any help, advice, or insight on how to achieve this task.

Comment: "I've tried reading about property placeholders but most of the examples are related to getting values from .yml files." - It may be that the examples you are looking at all happen to use values from `.yml` files but our property placeholder mechanism isn't really tied to that. Placeholders can be populated from micronaut config source including `.yml` files, `.properties` files, OS environment variables, JVM system properties, etc.

Comment: Thank you @JeffScottBrown maybe you have an example on how placeholders can be resolved from system properties or just a single object at runtime? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: `"maybe you have an example on how placeholders can be resolved from system properties"` - The code would look exactly the same regardless of where the value was coming from.  For example an annotation with something like `@SomeAnnotation("${some.config.setting}")` could be initialized with a value like `some.config.setting` which is defined in `application.yml`, the app could have been started with `-Dsome.config.setting=someValue`, there could be an OS environment variable named `SOME_CONFIG_SETTING`, etc.

Comment: That's clear for me but as I posted in the question I need to go a little further. For example `@SomeAnnotation("${someMethodParameter.someValue}")` to resolve when the aspect is executed.
For example
`@Override public Object intercept(final MethodInvocationContext<Object, Object> context) {
    // here get placeholder resolved based on the parameters passed to the method.
}`

Comment: I understand what you are wanting to do.  I was addressing the claim `"I've tried reading about property placeholders but most of the examples are related to getting values from .yml files."` to clarify that placeholders can be populated with values from a lot of places, including your own provider if you like, not just `.yml` files.